# Select connected subsets of integer pairs?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

Given a list of integer pairs such as

```
list = { {1,2},{1,3},{2,5},{1,5},{6,7},{6,9},{4,6} };
```

What is a quick way to separate the pairs into groups in which every element shares at least one integer with at least one other element, in Mathematica? e.g.:

```
separate[list]
```

> { { {1,2},{1,3},{2,5},{1,5} } , { {6,7},{6,9},{4,6} } }

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
G = Graph[{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 5}, {1, 5}, {6, 7}, {6, 9}, {4, 6}}];
Select[
 List @@@ EdgeList[Subgraph[G, #]] & /@ ConnectedComponents[G], 
 Length[#]>0 &
 ]
```

> {{{4, 6}, {6, 7}, {6, 9}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 5}, {1, 5}}}

If "quick" was meant as "quick at runtime", then you should better avoid `Graph` and use `SparseArray`:

```
componentEdges[edges_] := Module[{B},
   B = Transpose[With[{m = Length[edges], n = Max[edges]},
      (* this builds a sparse array directly from row pointers, column indices, and nonzero values; undocumentd *)
      SparseArray @@ {Automatic, {m, n}, 0, {1, {
          Range[0, 2 m, 2],
          Partition[Flatten[edges], 1]
          },
         ConstantArray[1, 2 m]}}
      ]];
   Select[
    Table[
     edges[[Flatten[(SparseArray[Partition[c, 1] -> 1, Length[B]].B)["NonzeroPositions"]]]],
     {c, SparseArray`StronglyConnectedComponents[B.B\[Transpose]]}],
    Length[#] > 0 &]
   ];
```

Just for comparison, the `Graph`-based approach:

```
componentEdges0[edges_] := With[{G = Graph[edges]},
   Select[
    List @@@ EdgeList[Subgraph[G, #]] & /@ ConnectedComponents[G], 
    Length[#] > 0 &]
   ];
```

And here a usage example along with timings:

```
edges = Developer`ToPackedArray[List @@@ EdgeList[RandomGraph[{10000, 60000}]]];
a = componentEdges0[edges]; // RepeatedTiming // First
b = componentEdges[edges]; // RepeatedTiming // First
Sort[Sort /@ a] == Sort[Sort /@ b]
```

> 0.13
>
> 0.0084
>
> True

Comment: But     G = Graph[{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 5}, {1, 5}, {6, 7}}];
Select[List @@@ EdgeList[Subgraph[G, #]] & /@ ConnectedComponents[G], 
 Length[#] > 0 &]                                      where {6, 7} shares no elts with others             returns the {6, 7}                       {{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 5}, {1, 5}}, {{6, 7}}}

Comment: @Rabbit Well, one could fix that by using the selector function `Length[#] > 1 &`. But I doubt that OP had that in mind...

Answer (score 6):

```
Gather[list, IntersectingQ]
```

> {{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 5}, {1, 5}},
>   {{6, 7}, {6, 9}, {4, 6}}}